# merge tables in R on specified fields

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have 2 csv files I want to merge on a linked key:

results.csv column headings:

```
schoolID, schoolName, Easting, Northing
123933, Mark College,   338371, 147812
139335, Hemsworth Arts and Community Academy,   442859, 413420
107563, Sowerby Bridge High School, 406122, 424146
137706, Willenhall E-ACT Academy,   398288, 300042
```

schools.csv column headings:

```
URN, LA (code), LA (name), EstablishmentNumber, EstablishmentName
123933, 201,    City of London, 3614,   Mark College
100001, 202,    Camden, 6005,   City of London School for Girls
139335, 201,    City of London, 6006,   Hemsworth Arts and Community Academy
100003, 201,    City of London, 6007,   City of London School
```

URN == schoolID and I want a final file showing data under column headings:

```
schoolID, schoolName, Easting, Northing, LA (name)
```

I've tried the following code:

```
res_data <- read.csv("C:/results.csv",
                       head=TRUE,sep=",")

school_data <- read.csv("C:/schools.csv",
                        head=TRUE,sep=",")

merge_data <- merge(x = res_data , y = school_data[c(1,3),], by.x = "schoolID", by.y = "URN" )

head(merge_data, 3)
```

But the result is just merging all the headings and not the data:

> schoolID, schoolName, Easting, Northing, URN, LA (code), LA (name), EstablishmentNumber, EstablishmentName

Comment: because I want  ''LA (name)'' data from the csv file and nothing else to be joined

Comment: no difference, the resulting merge is just a merge of all the headings with 0 data items: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names). Have updated question

Comment: Can you add a few lines from each of the csvs? Prefarably some which match.

Comment: have added some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with supplied test data

```
merge_data <- merge(x = res_data , y = school_data[,c(1,3)], by.x = "schoolID", by.y = "URN" )
```

(TWO changes!)

I think you've cut the third line instead the third column from school_data. You also need to include the merge column.

Comment: That and comment support above solves it. You need to have the search column in the y = school_data[c(3),] goes to: y = school_data[,c(1,3)]

Comment: I just update the explanation based on the supplied data. Thanks. I think c(1,3) is more elegant for your purpose.